# Is there a way to remove sites permanently from (my personal) Google search results?

Tags: google-search

I regularly find sites that copy content from elsewhere (mailing lists, etc) while not providing any added value. Quite to the contrary, they are pretty heaped with ads.

I'd like to remove those sites as permanently as possible from my Google search results. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use [this user script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/33156)

Comment: There are nice solutions with personal blocking extensions. However, it would be good that we could complain about such sites directly to google, so others could benifit from it without extensions. If you have any thought, please share.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can use a userscript, I found this to be an excellent replacement for functionality that used to be provided by [Personal Blocklist](http://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklist-by-goo/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef) (now discontinued):

https://www.jeffersonscher.com/gm/google-hit-hider/

Comment: This was a really nice experience to install. It takes only a few clicks, and works out of the box.

Comment: Unfortunately this extension no longer works (as of 2019).

Comment: @AndersonGreen What version of Chrome and operating system are you using? I'm on Chrome 73.0.3683.86 and macOS Mojave 10.14.3 and I'm still able to use it without any issues.

Comment: This link no longer works: [Personal Blocklist](http://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklist-by-goo/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef)

Comment: Since this is now a 404 just install UBlockOrigin and subscribe to https://filterlists.com/lists/blocklist-ligyxy this blocklist

Comment: @AnkurS The question is concerned with removing sites from Google search results, not blocking the user from visiting them.

Comment: I added a note that it is discontinued. Here https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/8dqoru/is_personal_blocklist_dead/ I have found another alternative called uBlacklist (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublacklist/pncfbmialoiaghdehhbnbhkkgmjanfhe) and it was already mentioned by @caduceus answer

Answer (score 36):

For Chrome users, the official [Personal Blocklist Chrome extension](http://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklist-by-goo/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef) can remove sites from your results. Unlike the one referenced in [Bernhard Hofmann's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/1429/354), this is an official extension developed by Google.

Google used to have built-in [support for this](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/03/hide-sites-to-find-more-of-what-you.html), but it has removed this feature. If you used this feature, you can still [download your block list as a text file](http://www.google.com/reviews/t).

Comment: this looks really nice. is there a way to avoid the tedious "return from google step?

Comment: Still not availble on my results, I'll be using @Bernhard's solution for now.

Comment: This is respected when I use Chrome. In Safari, none of my blocked domains are blocked. Imagine that...

Comment: @ripper234 be sure to block sub-domains too.

Comment: As of today it is not working for me. Would be perfect to filter all those crappy sites out there when I am feeling lazy and use Google as an entry point for SE (again).

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek: Yes, it looks like it was lost on one of the recent search results redesigns. If I can find out where it has gone I'll update my answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a link to Google's official support page where they say the feature is no longer supported. Like Bernhard, they recommend a Chrome extension, but they recommend their own, not a third party's.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this update, I couldn't find this info myself. Thats a bummer, though, because I just do not want to use Chrome... - So I will just have a large string of "-site:xyz.com ..." handy for that purpose, as I do now.

Comment: @Alex: There is at least one add-on for Firefox out there that does something similar.

Comment: The Personal Blocklist extension used to display a link inline to `block exampledomain.com` from your results. Does any extension currently provide this functionality?

Comment: Removed this as accepted answer as none of the linked sites seem to work any more for firefox (I don't use chrome), whereas the userscript answer I accepted now seems to work across all browsers.

Comment: That extension doesn't work as of October 2018.

Answer (score 17):

There is a Search Filter Chrome extension for filtering search results:

https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ddgjlkmkllmpdhegaliddgplookikmjf?hl=en-gb

Comment: This does exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: official Google extension: [Personal Blocklist](http://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklist-by-goo/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef)

Comment: @törzsmókus: Already referenced in [the accepted answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/13371/354).

Comment: When I try to install this, I get an error message stating that it has an invalid manifest. Does anyone know how to address this?

Comment: This link gives 404 now.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Chrome, you can create a custom search engine

this appends `-site:quora.com` to your search string and blocks quora from the search result

```
{google:baseURL}search?q=%s+-site:quora.com&{google:RLZ}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}{google:assistedQueryStats}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:iOSSearchLanguage}{google:searchClient}{google:sourceId}{google:contextualSearchVersion}ie={inputEncoding}
```

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. No plugins needed.

Comment: @GeoffreyHale it combines the minus operator to apply exclusion filter with the site filter. + Is just a separator, and %s is the string representing your search. +-site:quora.com+-site:w3schools.com

Comment: I also like this answer. Not everyone knows about the fact that we can add custom search engines in Google Chrome and it's basically just a wrapper around the URL it generates to send us to the search engine itself. With that answer, we can simply leverage the "-website.com" minus functionality to remove whole websites. You could even customize the whole advanced search syntax like always wrap your search query with quotes to force the exact keyword, etc. Wish I had thought of it before! 

Comment: But this is much more finger work than the uBlacklist solution mentioned by @caduceus.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [uBlacklist](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublacklist/pncfbmialoiaghdehhbnbhkkgmjanfhe/related?hl=en) Chrome extension by iorate

Comment: Notice, DuckDuckGo and other search engines have to be enabled explicitly in the options. Per default it only works on Google.

Comment: Also notice, in the options you can subscribe to blocklists made by other people. ["awesome-ublacklist"](https://github.com/rjaus/awesome-ublacklist/) is a small collection of such lists.

Answer (score 4):

For [uBlock](https://ublock.org/) users:
add line `google.*##.g:has(a[href*="unwanted.com"])` to "My filters".

Comment: This works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I sometimes use this solution when I have to search for specific topics, like **Hardware Reviews**, **Programming Issue**, etc.

I define a [Custom Search Engine](http://www.google.com/cse/) query, that works as a **white-list** of websites.

Follow the wizards and then save the HTML code provided by Google at the end on a file on your PC. When you have to do a certain type of search just open that file.

Answer (score 2):

I and many others have found the plugins don't work but you can create your own blocklist using a browser's native functions.

In Chrome, open *Settings* and click on *Manage Search Engines*.

Scroll down to the bottom and add a new search engine. You'll have to add a duplicate Google (call it whatever you like) and make that your default search engine because Chrome won't allow you to modify the search string for its Google entry.

In the rightmost field the base search string would be something like this (I live in oz) where %s = your search terms:

https://google.com.au/#q=%s

To exclude trash sites from your search, add them after the %s in URL format,  excluding 'Junk Site' and 'Spam Factory' would be:

https://google.com.au/#q=%s+-%22Junk+Site%22+-%22Spam+Factory%22

If you use Chrome's Omnibox (the URL / search bar at the top) it will automatically append this to your searches, e.g., `-"Junk Site" -"Spam Factory"`. If you use Google's search box (the one between "Google" and the little microphone) your search it won't, i.e., your search will be unfiltered.

Comment: Nice suggestion, however I would use -site:junksite.com instead of what you have here.

Answer (score 1):

**No**... there is is no current way to remove websites from your Google Search results.

At least, not if you are using Firefox as of 8/9/2011.

Answer (score 0):

There may be chances that some malware related software has been installed in your PC without being noticed to you. I had the same problem when I Google something you get unwanted search results.

There are two steps you can follow for removing those:

**1.** If you are using Google Chrome, go to
Settings -> Advanced option -> Reset and clean up -> Clean Up Computer.

**2.** Goto control panel -> Uninstall programmes
Sort the programs by their installed date.
Find the suspicious program and uninstall if any. ( Like SeachAwesome, Vebasearch etc.)

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner approach is [Google Hit Hider by Domain (Search Filter / Block Sites)](http://www.jeffersonscher.com/gm/google-hit-hider/), a Tampermonkey script that brings back block feature in search engines