# Any way to prevent certain websites from displaying in Google search results?

Tags: google-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to remove sites permanently from (my personal) google search results?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1397/is-there-a-way-to-remove-sites-permanently-from-my-personal-google-search-resul)

The website www.bigresource.com is completely useless but highly optimized for search engines. This bugs the heck outta me and wastes my time everyday.

Anyone know of any way to prevent a website from displaying on my Google search results (when logged into to my Google account, of course)?

Comment: What browser, some suggestions will be browser dependent?

Comment: @rchem, sure. But why complicate things? It's possible just using basic Google-fu.

Comment: The OP is asking for the term to be omitted for every search.  Typing out "-site:<site>" gets old pretty fast.  Asking for a way to automate it is valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a Chrome extension that will allow you to blacklist sites from your search results.

https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/hbodbmhopadphbloiimamkjmihekaejd

Firefox also has a similar addon:

<s>https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/12305/</s> (Add-on was removed by its author)
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hide-unwanted-results-of-go

Comment: @Merlin2001: That's two answers where you've inserted a link to the same Firefox extension. What's your affiliation? Please have a look at our [help/behavior].

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I do for Chrome:

1. Wrench > Options > Basics > Manage Search.
2. Edit the default Google Search
3. Change the Keyword to something else, "g_" for instance.
4. Copy the url.
5. Create a new search entry with Google (Custom) as the name, "g" as the Keyword, and the url you copied.
6. Add "+-site:bigresource.com" to the url.
7. Save it and make it the default.

Now whenever you search using the address bar in Chrome, it will append the site exclusion so that you don't have to type it each time.

Note:  This is not attached to your Google account at all and would not be applied on another computer unless it was configured there.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Google Labs feature that allows you to hide a specific search result from future keyword matches.

http://www.google.com/experimental/a840e102.html

Comment: This would need to be done for each keyword though, it isn't a global exclude.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way seems to be (certainly for Google):

search_term_1 search_term_2 ... search_term_*n* -site:[site-to-exclude]

I've tested this with the following terms, and it seemed to work happily each time (the links show the results of each search):

[html css jquery](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=css+html+jquery)

[html css jquery -site:jquery.com](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=css+html+jquery+-site:jquery.com)

Answer (score 0):

If you own the site you can request that Google remove the site using their URL removal tool in [Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/).

If you don't own the site, you're pretty much limited to contacting the webmaster and request that they use the URL removal tool.  Good luck with that :)