# Blacklisting parasite websites that copy Stack Overflow

Tags: google-search, browser-addons, blacklist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to remove sites permanently from (my personal) Google search results?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1397/is-there-a-way-to-remove-sites-permanently-from-my-personal-google-search-resu)

How can you configure a browser, and the search agent - e.g. Google - that it uses, to ignore websites like `efreedom.com` that are just copy-pastes of Stack Overflow?

In the same way there is adblock to block ads, is there any browser plugin that blocks all the noise?

Comment: So you want the ability to block yourself from accessing certain domains?

Comment: or did the OP meant they want to block said sites from search results?

Comment: I've just voted to migrate to Web Apps, but now I'm not so sure. The solutions to this fall in both sites - you can do stuff on your computer or you can configure how Google (a web app) works.

Comment: if the latter (to what @ChrisF said) then see http://superuser.com/questions/5631/is-it-possible-with-google-searches-to-ban-any-and-all-results-from-a-domain

Answer (score 5):

Use [Google Custom Search](http://www.google.com/cse/) to define your own search that will exclude these sites.

See this section in the help : [How can I exclude sites and pages?](http://www.google.com/support/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=70323).

Answer (score 4):

[Peter Steinberger](http://petersteinberger.com/) has developed a [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gledhololmniapejefjfocffkhoamlll?hl=en) and Safari extension called "stackoverflowerizer" that automatically redirects pages on efreedom.com, questionhub.com, etc. to the original StackOverflow page. It will rewrite your Google search results (to link directly to SO), but it won't remove the spam sites from Google.

Comment: Thanks for the link! This was really starting to bother me lately.

Comment: Here's a link to the Safari extension: https://github.com/steipete/stackoverflowerizer/raw/master/stackoverflowerizer.safariextz

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is to prevent yourself from accessing certain domains there are a few options that immediately jump to mind. None of these will stop google returning these sites as results, but you won't be able to access them when it does.

- Edit your `HOSTS` file.
- Configure your router (if your router supports blocking of domains).
- Use a DNS service that supports filtering and/or blacklisting (such as [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/)).

Editing the `HOSTS` file has the advantage that it will work where ever the modified machine is (so on a laptop if you are constantly moving around it will work everywhere), this may also be the case for the DNS service if you configure it directly on the computer.

The latter two (assuming you configure the DNS change at the router) have the advantage of effecting your entire local network from only one configuration point.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [this](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/18527) [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748/) script.  I haven't tried it myself, but it was <strike>recently updated, so it should</strike> updated a year ago, but it will still work with Google's current results page, although instant search needs to be off.  Simply edit the script and add the unwanted sites to the list of blocked sites.

Answer (score 1):

Place an entry in your `hosts`† file that associates the efreedom.com domain names with the ip-addresses of (say) stackoverflow.com.

This won't affect Google's results but clicking them will take you to wherever you have configured.

† e.g. `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows XP.

Comment: `hosts` file management.. can be a pain, no ?