# How to exclude a domain from Google search?

Tags: google-search

I would like to do a search query and filter out all results from www.foo.com. How do I do that?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This may help: (From this site:
https://web.archive.org/web/20141223223234/http://www.greghughes.net/rant/HowToExcludeADomainFromYourGoogleSearchResults.aspx)

"Note the "minus sign" that precedes the `site:` search operator in this case. That's how we tell Google to exclude the site/domain specified.

So there you have it. Want to exclude a domain from your search term? Just specify the domain with "-site:" and you're all set.

But what if you don't want to specify the domain to exclude every time by hand? In that case, set up a Google Custom Search Engine (http://www.google.com/coop/cse/) and specify during setup that you want your custom search engine to include results from the entire Internet. Then, after your search engine has been created, go to the Control Panel, choose the "Sites" tab, and from there you can specify as many domains as you like to exclude from every search. You'll get a custom search engine that you can tweak to your heart's content."

Comment: Latest addition, you can block domains now from your search, see: https://www.google.com/reviews/t

Comment: Domain block is not defunct as part of Google. I have resorted back to -site: as above, but I use a text expander to open up my whole list of domains I'd rather not see. I answered a similar questions here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30198/block-sites-from-appearing-in-bing-search-results/61166#61166

Comment: Looks like this site is down. A full example should be edited in to improve the quality of the answer per SO's new guidelines.

Comment: Please don’t use a link as an answer. This answer does not actually say how to omit a domain.

Answer (score 12):

You can exclude a domain by combining operators, so if you want to search for `example` but not see stuff from example.com, you can input `example -site:example.com`.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Choice

[image: HUROGS] Firefox addon [**Hide Unwanted Results of Google Search**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/hide-unwanted-results-of-go/) — is my choice.

---

### 2. Limits

You need to use Firefox.

**If** you want to use Chrome, possibly, you can help [**this**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/10543/122122) and [**this**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/13371/122122) answers.

---

### 3. Environment

Addon successful works for me in:

- Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB 64-bit EN,
- Firefox 54.0.1 (64-bit).

---

### 4. Demonstration

SERP without filters:

[image: Without filters]

For example, I want to exclude YouTube and IMDb. Right-click to link of YouTube and IMDb in SERP → select `Add This site to Hide Results` → results hide:

[image: Hide results]

You can see and manage excluded domains. `about:addons` → find `Hide Unwanted Results of Google Search` → `Options` → `Settings…`:

[image: Addons page]

You can temporarily turn on excluded sites, **if** you unchecked mark.

[image: Unchecked]

---

### 5. Features

1. You can forever hide results from unexpected site(s). **If** you use `-site:`, operator from [**@Su answer**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/29989/122122), you need wrote `-site:` operator each time, as you want exclude site. It may take a lot of time.
2. Multiple sites excluding support,
3. Regular expressions supports for excluding parts of domains.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Xavierjazz](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/6284/xavierjazz)' excellent [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/9708/280816), you can use the [`inurl`](https://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators_reference.html#inurl) search parameter to exclude URLs with a particular word in it:

```
-inurl:foo.com
```

This becomes handy, if you do not want to exclude the whole domain, but only certain paths:

```
-inurl:foo.com/path/to/uninteresting/content
```

In contrast to the [`site`](https://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators_reference.html#site) search parameter, `inurl` can be applied to multiple domains, while still using one keyword:

```
-inurl:uninteresting
```

will exclude `www.foo.com/uninteresting` and `www.bar.com/uninteresting` for example.