# Ignore watermarked stock pictures from image search

Tags: google-image-search

When I search for images on Google, mostly it gives results related to stock websites with watermarked images. I want these sites to be ignored when I perform a search—is there any possibility to do it?

Comment: You can exclude a single site with `-site:example.com`, which can be repeated for each site you want to exclude. Does that suffice?

Comment: Check the answers to [this question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/10522/1512) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Watermarks could be applied to "force" users to ask for the appropriate permission to reuse the image, as a way to enforce the appropriate attribution, or to make clear that there are some "usage rights" that should be considered.

> ## Find images that you can reuse
>
> When you do a Google Search, you can filter your results to find
> images, videos, or text that you have permission to use. To do this,
> you’ll use an Advanced Search filter called "usage rights" that lets
> you know when you can use, share, or modify something you find online.

## References

- [Find images that you can reuse - Search Help](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/29508?hl=en)