# Exclude a certain page from Google search

Tags: google-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to exclude a domain from Google search?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9707/how-to-exclude-a-domain-from-google-search)

Is there a way, when I'm using Google search, to construct the query such that it will not show me the results from a certain page? In other words, let's imagine I want to exclude the search page from a certain domain, could I do so?