# How to let Google learn about me in order to customise search results?

Tags: google-search

I mean, for example: I don't like `www.w3schools.com` so I’d like to tell Google: "never show me this" instead of writing the `–` operator all the time.

It would be nice also if by writing `ms SQL` Google searched for `MS SQL server` (not MySql)—because I'm interested in this particular engine.

Is it possible to somehow let Google learn from my activity in the web?

Comment: For the first part of your question, see: [Is there a way to remove sites permanently from (my personal) Google search results?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/1397/354)