# Permanently exclude / blacklist site from search results on DuckDuckGo

Tags: duckduckgo

Using [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com), it's possible to temporarily remove a specific site from search results by adding `-site:example.com` to the search query.

Is there a way to permanently block/blacklist/exclude undesired websites from search results? I didn't find anything in the DDG settings but maybe there is some Greasemonkey script or Firefox extension out there that could do the trick?

Comment: You§re asking for script recommendation... Use google for that.

Comment: no, i'm asking for any kind of way to achieve this. exactly like [this](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1397/is-there-a-way-to-remove-sites-permanently-from-my-personal-google-search-resu) question (about a different search engine) which has 49 upvotes at the time of writing this. if there's something wrong with my question, then there's something wrong with that one as well.

Comment: This question is okay, since there's a definite problem to be solved. A script or extension is just one way to do it. Obviously the Asker is open to any sort of solution.

Comment: That said, @foerno, you should have a look at [How do I ask a question that may require recommending a web app?](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/3705/354)

Comment: Thanks for asking this. I need a way to keep w3schools out of my results

Comment: @BradyDowling haha you should check the revision history for this question. :)

Comment: @foerno it's beautiful and hideous at the same time 

Comment: (Not enough reputation) You don't have to install anything. Chrome example: create a new custom search in [ Settings › Search engine › Manage ], set URL `https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%s+-site%3Aexample.com`, (shortcut doesn't matter), save and then make it the default via ellipsis context menu. If the option is greyed out then delete the other installed-by-default DuckDuckGo entry which Chrome won't let you edit.

Comment: @WoodrowShigeru not enough reputation for what? you don't need reputation to post an answer AFAIK. and comments are not for answers.

Comment: `Highly active question. Earn 10 reputation (not counting the association bonus) in order to answer this question. The reputation requirement helps protect this question from spam and non-answer activity.`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`ublacklist`](https://github.com/iorate/uBlacklist) is an extension which lets you remove sites from search results.

Note that by default it works with Google, but you can enable DuckDuckGo and other search engines in the options.

Comment: [You can also subscribe to blocklists](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1397/is-there-a-way-to-remove-sites-permanently-from-my-personal-google-search-resu#comment152059_129364).

Answer (score 6):

With [a standard URL rewrite/redirect pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675049/greasemonkey-add-parameters-to-url), you could use a Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey/generic userscript like:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        DuckDuckGo, Always add certain search parameters
// @match       *://*.duckduckgo.com/*
// @run-at      document-start
// @noframes
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

//--- SET THIS NEXT VARIABLE TO TASTE.
//--- Seperate multiple site with the | key. i.e. -site:wikipedia.org|bbc.co.uk
var stickySrchTerm  = "-site:wikipedia.org";

var stckySrchEncdd  = encodeURIComponent (stickySrchTerm);
var oldUrlSearch    = location.search;

//--- Test that haven't already redirected.
if ( ! oldUrlSearch.includes (stckySrchEncdd) ) {
    //--- Our term must go in the `q=` portion of `location.search`.
    var srchParams  = oldUrlSearch.split ("&");
    for (var J = 0, L = srchParams.length;  J < L;  J++) {
        if (/^\??q=/.test (srchParams[J]) ) {
            srchParams[J] += "+" + stckySrchEncdd;
            break;
        }
    }
    var newUrlSearch    = srchParams.join ("&");
    var newURL          = location.protocol + "//"
                        + location.host
                        + location.pathname
                        + newUrlSearch
                        + location.hash
                        ;
    /*-- replace() puts the good page in the history instead of the
        bad page.
    */
    location.replace (newURL);
}
```