# Google Search results vs. full page of spam links

Tags: google-search, spam-prevention

I've searched for `ext:PDF` (filetype version) of a probably popular = commercial successful book and got [full page (maybe more) of spam links - it's more than 100](https://www.google.lt/search?num=100&q=%22The%20Personal%20MBA%3A%20Master%20the%20Art%20of%20Business%22%20ext%3Apdf)!

How to deal with a full page of spam links in the google search results, how to get more relevant results?

- Somehow put all (un-relevant) domains into the filter?
- Report all of them - impossible task or must be automated?
- Other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[After some research found this way](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/119052/101870) Google Hit Hider lets you hide sites from your Google search results that you do not care to see. It also works on DuckDuckGo, Startpage.com, Bing and Yahoo.

Answer (score 0):

If you find information in Google's search results that you believe result from spam, paid links or malware, here's how you can report it:

**SPAM** - **https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/spamreport**

> If the site is spam, tell us about it! Google takes spam extremely
>   seriously, and investigates reported instances. These reports are
>   submitted directly to our webspam team and are used to devise scalable
>   solutions to fight spam.

**PAID LINKS** - **https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/paidlinks?pli=1**

> Buying or selling links that pass PageRank can dilute the quality of
>   search results. Participating in link schemes violates the Googles
>   Webmaster Guidelines and can negatively impact a site's ranking in
>   search results. If you believe a site is engaged in buying or selling
>   links that pass PageRank, please tell us about it.

**MALWARE** - **http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/report_badware/**

> If you believe the site is infected with malware or malicious
>   software, please report it to us so we can take action as necessary.

**BONUS:** copy/paste this into the search box and the first result should be valid:
`"The Personal MBA: Master the Art of Business" ext:pdf .pdf`
not sure if this is actually what you seek: **[link to pdf](https://changethis.com/manifesto/98.02.PersonalMBA/pdf/98.02.PersonalMBA.pdf)**

Comment: Thanks for Bonus. But in general - this is useless info regarding my specific question - you are suggesting to report (manually?!) all those 100+ spam-links?

Comment: @AndriuZ unfortunately yes. there is no mass-report option. you can do it one by one if you got bored some day or just not report it and save a time

Comment: Maybe I need to rephrase my question. I'm not against reporting (even 100+) above all it's good for society (if Google really cares), but not much help for me (regarding future perspective). Any other options?

Comment: @AndriuZ not sure what do you want to do apart of reporting it or not to. your search criteria is ok and if there wasnt be any spam you would find it easily.

Comment: IFR (ideal final result) for me should be 'no spam links at all'. So final result of reporting should minimise (exlude) reported sites from search results. I understand it's unrealistic scenario. So probably other solution (personal or public) could be some kind of 'filter list'. Maybe custom list for uBlocker / other blocker or browser addon https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/g-search-filter/